# Table headername & dropdown in one cell

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, dropdown

I need help with an issue I have.

A table has a headername and I’m showing next to headername an icon like this:

1. when mouse hover the cell only the icon is shown
2. while hover over the icon the icon is shown and a background
3. when clicking onto the icon the dropdown is shown

Now I have a problem with the drop-down cause it gonna be closed when mouse leaves the area. If I remove the mouseleave then it will not work with the hover effect at the cell.

How can I create one cell with headername and a drop-down while the dropdown doesn’t use the effects of the cell when opened ?

**dashboard.vue**

```
<template>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col" class="hover-cell">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                        First
                        <LeadsTableDropdown />
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
                <th scope="row">{{ index + 1 }}</th>
                <td>{{ item.first }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.last }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.handle }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import LeadsTableDropdown from '@/Components/LeadsTableDropdown.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        LeadsTableDropdown
    },
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                { first: 'Mark', last: 'Otto', handle: '@mdo' },
                { first: 'Jacob', last: 'Thornton', handle: '@fat' },
                { first: 'Larry', last: 'the Bird', handle: '@twitter' },
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```css
<style scoped>
.hover-cell .dropdown {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.hover-cell:hover .dropdown {
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

**LeadsTableDropdown.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn-icon" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="bi bi-three-dots"></i>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
    // ...
}
</script>
```

```css
<style scoped>
.btn-icon {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: black;
}

.btn-icon:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
</style>
```